# Xampp - Can't start Apache after install SQL Server and Visual Studio

Tags: windows, apache, iis, xampp

my computer was installed IIS and I using xampp without problem. 

But when i installed **SQL Server and Visual Studio**. My **apache can't start**.

I check by cmd like
[image]

and 
[image]

But i can't end task because it's disable.
How can i make my apache run thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found my solution:

 **Stop** service **SQL Server Reporting Services**

I see below thread
http://www.lukebrowning.com/blog/nt-kernel-system-using-port-80/

Answer (score 1):

**After install Sql** server , there will be reporting services configuration manager which is actually blocking the **port 80**. Follow the steps to release the port for xampp

- **logon your reporting services configuration manager**

[image]

- **Go to Web Service URL > Advances**

[image]

- **Then Click on Edit in first edit button and change the TCP port and click save.** 
  [image]
- **Then Click on Report Manager URL > Advanced > Edit (First Edit Button) > Change port 80 to 8080 > ok

** [image]

Answer (score 0):

Apache wan't start after Microsoft VS, IIS, MYSQL installation.

I run the command: netstat -aon | findstr :80 
I figured out that the MSSQL was listening port :80

There are two solutions:

- Use different port for Apache what is not convenient but esentiel if you need MSSQL up during development.
- Stop MSSQL server. CMD -> Services.msc-> SQL Server -> Stop

[image: Stop MSSQL in a services]