# apache is not working on xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

It shows the errors given bellow

```
9:53:45 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
9:53:45 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
9:53:45 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:53:45 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:53:45 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:53:45 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
9:53:45 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

please help me

Comment: Have you installed skype or another software that creating the port conflicts ?? try getting whch port is listening to whom in windows -->netstat -b -a

Comment: Try restart your system.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly

Comment: sometimes other service use port 80 by default so it is advisable to change

Answer (score 0):

The default port for apache- 80, is used by some other application.

So, you can change the port number from 80 to something else (8080) in httpd.conf in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

For e.g.- 
   Change default `Listen 80` to

```
Listen 8080
```

Comment: DONE Successfully, Thanks to all.