# XAMPP error message

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I downloaded the xampp but have the following errors:
I really need help I am not a programmer and just a user and would like to use typo3 to create a website using Xampp.

```
12:14:00  [Apache]  Status change detected: running 
12:14:00  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
12:14:00  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:14:00  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:14:00  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:14:00  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:14:00  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:14:00  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
12:14:00  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

please any one help to use XAMPP apache without error .......

Comment: reply with simple steps to solve this issue

Comment: are you run skype on your pc now? if yes. then first close skype then retry to start xampp

Comment: are you using windoww or ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this question:
[apache is not working on xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693498/apache-is-not-working-on-xampp?rq=1)

You need to find the httpd.conf file and Listen section. Try to change it to something else (if you have e.g. 80, change it to 8080 or 9090) and try to start Apache again.

Answer (score 0):

change port no in xampp. error occur due to same port no skype 8080 and xampp server port no is 8080 same. so change the port no 8085 in xampp init file

it may help you