# XAMPP Apache service stopped

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am not able to run Apache and getting bellow errors from XAMPP Control Panel. When this happens I have re-install Windows... not sure but I am assuming. I have installed XAMPP from D Drive.

```
5:34:35 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
5:34:35 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
5:34:35 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
5:34:35 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:34:35 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:34:35 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
5:34:35 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Note: Before posting this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18300377/1948428) I have read this question but no luck.

How to fix Apache error?

Answer (score 0):

These are the things I usually do/check when I have this kind of issues:

1. Disable Windows Firewall
2. Remove applications that use port 80 or change its port to something else than 80 (another Apache installation, wamp, Skype, etc)
3. Start xampp as administrator (right-click xampp icon in desktop > run as administrator)
4. Some commands I use for troubleshooting: `netstat`, `telnet`
5. Read Windows Event Viewer for more information (Go to Windows and type `eventvwr.exe` and `ENTER`)
6. You can also change xampp's port to `81` or `8080`