# Apache server not running after installing SSL

Tags: windows, apache, openssl, xampp, ssl-certificate

I am trying to enable SSL on Apache Server (XAMPP) on Windows Server 2012 R2. I have a signed certificate from a Certificate Authority.

Following the installation instructions, I copied the private key, Server Certificate and Intermediate CA certificate properly to right directory and also made necessary certificates name path settings in httpd-ssl file.

Now when i am trying to start Apache through Xampp it is giving me following error:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:42:29 This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:42:29 improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:42:29 Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:42:29 the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:42:29 If you need more help, copy and post this
12:42:29 entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: please post your httpd.conf file/settings too

Comment: I have kept default and not made any changes in httpd file. As SSL mode is by default on there and by default virtual host file and ssl file is included there.

Comment: do you have Skype or some other tool running on the server that is using port number 80 or 443?

Comment: No sir i donot have SKype... But i try to figure Out... It is saying Port 443 is closed. Also then i try with other Ports for ssl like 442 or 4430. Same results. Apache was unable to start.

Comment: Have you added Listen 443 in the httpd.conf file, please refer to this thread it might he helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly

Comment: Thank you @Shiva For all your help. FInally it is resolved now.The Error is because of "SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32" I followed this link and got it run. Thanks "https://support.quovadisglobal.com/KB/a90/i-get-error-message-error-init-sslpassphrasedialog.aspx" again

Answer (score 2):

Finally error is resolved now. The Error is because of "SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32". I followed this link and got it working.  "https://support.quovadisglobal.com/KB/a90/i-get-error-message-error-init-sslpassphrasedialog.aspx" Thanks again.