# Apache cannot start in XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm getting this error when trying to start Apache in my XAMPP installation:

> Status change detected:stopped.
>   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues.

What is wrong?

Comment: `This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues.` this sounds helpful.

Comment: Look at the logs and latest error to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your port 80 to port 8080 in httpd.conf file.

Like this :
 From :Listen 80 
To : Listen 8080

Comment: still cannot be. my apache cannot be start.

Comment: i won't suggest using 8080, it is by default tomcat's.

Comment: Try to restart it, and even though there's still an error, try to go to your browser and type localhost:8080.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the port has been occupied by any other applications like Skype.

If you are using Skype in your PC, just `quit` Skype and `restart` Apache.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because the port 80 that xampp uses by default is in use by another application. Most of the times its Skype.
You have 2 options to solve this issue:
1. Stop the application that is using the port. But this is not the good thought. right?
2. Configure your xampp apache server to use some other port than port 80. This is explained very well in this post http://webolute.com/blog/programming/this-may-be-due-to-a-blocked-port-missing-dependencies
Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

It might because the port is used by some software you have been using, 
please try to check on your XAMPP if there were VMware or skype port existing.

and then please refer to this solution :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826733/6512015