# Xampp Apache Service(Not a Skype Port conflict)

Tags: apache, xampp

Unable to start Apache service on XAMPP

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:18:40 PM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:18:40 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:18:40 PM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:18:40 PM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:18:40 PM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:18:40 PM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP, Apache - Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Comment: There is no Skype on my machine, can someone please help me out?

Comment: Read the other answers provided at the link, some of them are not about skype