# Apache Server for PHP Programming

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I tried to open XAMPP program and run for executing PHP files offline but the APACHE is not starting

> 1. 11:36:51 AM  [Apache]     Attempting to start Apache app...
> 2. 11:36:51 AM  [Apache]     Status change detected: running
> 3. 11:36:53 AM  [Apache]     Status change detected: stopped
> 4. 11:36:53 AM  [Apache]     Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
> 5. 11:36:53 AM  [Apache]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing     dependencies,
> 6. 11:36:53 AM  [Apache]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
> 7. 11:36:53 AM  [Apache]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
> 8. 11:36:53 AM  [Apache]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
> 9. 11:36:53 AM  [Apache]     If you need more help, copy and post this
>
>    10. 11:36:53 AM  [Apache]     entire log window on the forums

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly search before ask ;)

Comment: It's not working i tried

Comment: Another post help me solved it it said to rename port no from 80 to 8080 in a config file and port no 443 to 4433 in an another config file which comes under the button confid in XAMPP control panel in apache row! anyways thanks Dave