# update php folder xampp for install curl_reset()

Tags: xampp, php-5.5

A new version of a program written in the PHP in XAMPP install I had trouble in error openssl.dll, curl_reset () to install the new version of PHP 5.5, how can I fix PHP XAMPP folder with the new version will replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to install the new version of the program, may not install the new version with the error encountered port 80 by performing the following steps, you can download it and trouble-free installation...

1. download new xampp [apachefriends](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)
2. install it
3. remove all VPN app
4. open folder XAMPP  run setup_xampp.bat
5. run xampp-control.exe Or [apache-shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly/35669156)