# xampp: apache start for 1 sec and shutdwon

Tags: mysql, apache, shutdown

Apache not running :

---

My xampp configuration for apache is changed to :

> apache prot: 80 > 81 
>   apache ssl port : 443 > 1378
>
> apache run as `administrator`
>
> before run xampp i'm stop `IIS services` and `disable` startup
>
> MySQL is `running` but apache run in `1 sec` and shutdown !!!

that is xampp log :

```
15:10:36  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
15:10:36  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
15:10:37  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
15:10:37  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
15:10:37  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
15:10:37  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
15:10:37  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
15:10:37  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
15:10:37  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
15:10:37  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

and that's apache logs :

```
[Fri Mar 11 15:04:13.976216 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4052:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:1378:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Mar 11 15:04:14.085597 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4052:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:1378:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Mar 11 15:04:14.116853 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4052:tid 384] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 11 15:04:14.116853 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4052:tid 384] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Fri Mar 11 15:04:14.116853 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4052:tid 384] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Mar 11 15:04:14.116853 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4052:tid 384] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4088
[Fri Mar 11 15:04:14.601248 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3280:tid 376] AH01909: www.example.com:1378:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Mar 11 15:04:14.710628 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3280:tid 376] AH01909: www.example.com:1378:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Mar 11 15:04:14.741882 2016] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 3280:tid 376] (OS 6)The handle is invalid.  : AH00389: Child: Unable to access the scoreboard from the parent
[Fri Mar 11 15:04:14.741882 2016] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 4052:tid 384] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you change anything httpd.conf file?

Comment: If Skype is running, try closing it and restarting Apache.

Comment: dear MrD  : i'm not have Skype .

Comment: What changes you did in that file?

Comment: i change the httpd.conf  file (Listen 80) >>> (Listen 8080) and in httpd-ssl.conf file (Listen 443) >>> (Listen 4433) and it's done ! it works :). source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly