# xampp is not working properly Apache is not working

Tags: apache, xampp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8JVL.jpg)

Help me to fix this problem when i am executing any php script this dialog box will appear in XAMPP how to fix it please help me

Comment: Can you provide more information on your setup? ie. your xampp configuration, the php script causing this problem, any output from the logs, etc

Comment: i have maid some changes in xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf and now code is executing but i am not able to access phpmyadmin and my database

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem a week ago i fixed with following:

in `xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`

**Set Comment on following line.**

```
#LoadFile "D:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
#LoadModule php5_module "D:/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
#</FilesMatch>
#<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
#</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
```

**Uncomment the following line**:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule actions_module>
    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
</IfModule>
```

After changing this configuration I will never received APPCRASH. My problem is solved.

Please restart apache and other service from xampp control panel.

It help me from last week i don't get any app crash so hope it will help you also.

Comment: brother it is working now but i am not able to run phpmyadmin help me

Comment: in xampp control pannel apache and mysql both are in runnning state?

Comment: yes both are in running state only but localhost/phpmyadmin is not accessible

Comment: in xampp control pannel apache and mysql both are in runnning i am not able to Access Localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: able to access localhost:7777 ?

Comment: how to attach a screen shot here in comment line

Comment: localhost:7777 is also not Accessible

Comment: you can't put screen shot in comment. you can do update your question with screen shot or upload your screenshot on dropbox or google drive and share it's link here

Comment: ok do one thing, in above answer do only "**Uncomment the following line:**" part, don't do "**Set Comment on following line.**" and then restart apache and mysql. and ping me back

Comment: or do one thing change port number with change in **xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf** and change following line for port 8012.

Comment: 1) **Listen 80** to **Listen 8012**
2) **ServerName localhost:80** to**ServerName localhost:8012**
and restart apache and mysql and try yo access localhost:8012 iand let me know issue

Comment: It si showing CGI/FASTCGI Stoped working now and pHpMyadmin is working But code is not going to excute

Comment: Add this to your httpd-xampp.conf:

**Alias /phpmyadmin "D:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "D:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    Options ExecCGI
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>**

Comment: Same problem after changing 8012 Php My admin is not working

Comment: see my last comment

Comment: No brother phpmyadmin is not working help me to fix it

Comment: after that Apache is not getting started

Comment: seriously not getting issue. do one thing take **htdocs** folder back up remove complety xampp and install fresh one try to run localhost:7777 hope you get success. fingure crossed/

Comment: Now i re installed XAMMP BUt now Apache is not working

Comment: is there any other tomcat running on same machine?

Comment: Attempting to start Apache app...
12:28:13 PM  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
12:28:13 PM  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
12:28:13 PM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:28:13 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:28:13 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:28:13 PM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

Comment: do only following and try again:

 
or do one thing change port number with change in xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf and change following line for port 8012. – Naitik 1 hour ago   
     
1) Listen 80 to Listen 8012 2) ServerName localhost:80 toServerName localhost:8012 and restart apache and mysql and try yo access localhost:8012 iand let me know issue – Naitik 1 hour ago

Comment: we are changing port

Comment: Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:54:47 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:54:47 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:54:47 PM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:54:47 PM  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:54:47 PM  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
12:54:47 PM  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: is there any other tomcat running on same machine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly

Comment: same problem bro that is my main question that dailog box is comming

Comment: Ok now do only uncomment one from my answer

Comment: Apache HTTP Server is stoped working Dialog box it came to fist problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly try one of them