# wordpress database connection error / manually changed php port

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I had to change the apache port to 7777 in windows 10 since apache refused to start with xampp.

I know this is affecting my local installation of wordpress, but what should I do?

I also changed the php port, but I still get an error in wordpress.

[image]

I manually created a wp-config.php file with the following values:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:7777');
```

But the only thing I was able to to is get the following notice:

> The file 'wp-config.php' already exists. If you need to reset any of
>   the configuration items in this file, please delete it first. You may
>   try installing now.

So, what is the correct way to install wordpress when you manually change the apache port?

Comment: can you change the port for Apache so iT wont run on 7777?

Comment: you mean use different ports for php and apache, instead the same one?

Comment: Mysql and Apache have the same ports, so try to change one of them to be unique

Comment: Done that and still, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apache and MySQL cannot be on the same port.  Take Apache off 7777.  You may need to restart it or restart your computer for it to properly release the port.  Then restart MySQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was a combination of the solutions showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27588802/490929):

disabling Skype's use of ports and configuring bot http and https ports as described in the aforementioned post.

Also, I made a new installation using Bitnami's Wordpress addon.