# What's XAMPP? Can anyone help me with its mySQL error?

Tags: java, xampp

I am developing a Java program and I was recommended to install XAMPP. Still, I am not sure if it is secure or not to my home computer. Is it dangerous or should I keep it? Sorry, I do not know anything about XAMPP.

Also, I started running it because I am doing a tutorial, and I came across the following error: http://prntscr.com/drwra6

Can anyone help me? Please, do not use difficult concepts :)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

## Short Answer

Uninstall Sype

## Long Answer

Open Skype.

Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection.

Disable the "Use port 80 and 443 for alternatives for incoming connections"

Sign Out and Close all Skype windows. Try restarting your Apache.

## VERY LONG ANSWER

As I am working in a corporate environment where developers faces firewall issues, none of the other answers resolved my issue.

As the port is not used by Skype, but by some other internal applications, I followed the below steps to resolve the issue:

Step 1 - From the XAMPP Control Panel, under Apache, click the Config button, and select the Apache (httpd.conf).

Inside the httpd.conf file, somehow I found a line that says:

Listen 80
And change the 80 into any number / port you want. In my scenario I’m using port 8080.

Listen 8080
Still from the httpd.conf file, I found another line that says:

ServerName localhost:80

And change 80 to 8080.

ServerName localhost:8080
Step 2 - From the XAMPP Control Panel, under Apache, click the Config button again, but this time select the Apache (httpd-ssl.conf). Inside the httpd-ssl.conf file, find line that says

Listen 443
And change the 443 into any number / port you want. I’ll using 4433 as the new port number.

Listen 4433
Still from the httpd-ssl.conf file, find another line that says

ServerName localhost:443
And change 443 to 4433.

ServerName localhost:4433
Remember to save the httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf files after performing some changes. Then restart the Apache service.

SOURCE [XAMPP, Apache - Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly)

## CONCLUSION

Google first

Comment: I have just uninstalled Skype and I am following your next steps. However, when I try to save the httpd.conf and the other archive, it says that I do not have permission to save it there, Do you know what can be done?

Comment: if youre in ubuntu you have to chmod 0777 all files and if youre windows try opening as admin from cmd