# Xampp won't start apache after reinstall

Tags: apache, xampp

I have a problem with my apache server. The guy in my team who was in charge is now gone and I can't understand anything of all this. Basically I have this error after uninstalling and reinstalling XAMPP when I try to start the server:

```
11:26:15  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:26:15  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:26:15  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:26:15  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:26:15  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:26:15  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
11:26:15  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

I have browsed stackoverflow and found many similar problems but almost all of them are about Skype using the ports 80 and 443, but I am not using Skype.
I also checked if anything was running on these ports, nothing is... I tried to change the port in the XAMPP configuration files and the problem was still not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem. I had mistakes in my `httpd-vhost.conf` file. The `DocumentRoot` and `directory` variables were wrong.

Thanks for the help DopeX!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something is blocking your port.
I had this issue as well some time ago.

A temporarily fix was to change the port 443 to something like 4430.

- Open xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd_ssl_conf with notepad
- change Listen 443 to Listen 4430

After this step you should be able to start XAMPP.
It seems to be a problem with the SSL port.

If it is still not working you could try:

- Open xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd_conf with notepad
- change Listen 80 to Listen 81

Hope this will help, but might be only temporarily fix.

Comment: I have the exam same problem after this change

Comment: I tried that as well and the same problem still occurs

Comment: Tried [Click me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27588802/6796170) this?
It seems like the port is still blocked by any process.

Comment: Still have the very same problem

Comment: Solved! I had mistakes in my httpd-vhost.conf file. The DocumentRoot and directory variables were wrong.

Thanks for the help DopeX!