# After changing Apache Server ports the localhost sites are not opening

Tags: php, apache

I was repeatedly getting this error "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly". I had to make repeated attempts to get apache server running. So I followed an answer by user "Min2" on stackoverflow at this link [XAMPP, Apache - Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly) and changed my apache ports. Now the apache starts at one go and runs properly without shutting down like before. But when I try to access my site like before at `localhost/mysite` it doesn't open. What can be the issue? Tagging PHP in the question as to get help from experienced developers. Please forgive me for the irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 0):

If the port differs from the default ports 80 (http) or 443 (https) you need to define the port in the url.
Say you have choosen 8080 as new port then you need to navigate to
localhost:8080/mysite

Comment: isn't there another way to change the port but access by localhost/ instead of localhost:8080?