# How to fix XAMPP "Apache / mysql shutdown unexpectedly" error

Tags: php, server, xampp

I was setting up a PHP server because I wrote some PHP code:
I  opened XAMPP and it said:

> 18:36:08  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 18:36:08  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 18:36:08  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 18:36:08  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums
>
> 18:36:23  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
>
> 18:36:23  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 18:36:23  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 18:36:23  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 18:36:23  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums

What is happening???

Comment: [You can read some answers to the same problem as you, maybe this can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27588802/13748685)

Answer (score -1):

There issue with port.

1. Open Skype. Go to `Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection`.
2. Uncheck the `Use port 80 and 443 for alternatives for incoming connections`  checkbox
3. Sign Out and Close all Skype windows.
4. Try restarting your Apache.

Comment: But I don't have Skype