# Apache Not Starting after adding a virtual host

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I added a virtual host in httpd-vhosts.conf as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/basicwebsite/public"
    ServerName basicwebsite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

and I also uncommented `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` from https.conf as suggested in similar threads. 
I also added `127.0.0.1 basicwebsite.dev` in `windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`.

Now when I start Apache it gives the following error

```
12:07:33 PM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:07:33 PM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:07:33 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:07:33 PM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:07:33 PM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:07:33 PM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:07:33 PM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

When I remove the VirtualHost from `httpd-vhosts.conf`, Apache starts working smoothly again..

What I am doing wrong?
Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Open httpd.conf file present in C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
Remove the #(hash) sign present to include the “httpd-vhosts.conf” file in httpd.conf file.

## Virtual hosts

#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

To

## Virtual hosts

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Step 2:

Create a virtualhost file. Open “httpd-vhosts.conf” file. And copy the below lines of code.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
  DocumentRoot <PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_HERE>
  ServerName <SERVER_NAME like local.pos.com>
</VirtualHost>
```

Replace PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_HERE & SERVER_NAME with appropriate values, Save the file.

Step3:

Open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Add the below line at the end of file.

```
127.0.0.1      <SERVER_NAME like local.pos.com>
```

Restart apache server and visit the site URL.

That’s all is needed to set up a virtual host.

Comment: Done that already as mentioned in my question, but as soon as I complete this process, the apache doesn't starts at all.. and the moment i remove the virtual host from httpd-vhosts, it starts working again.

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Directory tag in your VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/basicwebsite/public"
    ServerName basicwebsite.dev
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/basicwebsite/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```