# Xampp apache not starting

Tags: apache, xampp, port, blocked

Apache in xampp was not starting with port 80 and 443 so, I changed the port number 80 to 10080 and 443 to 10443.But it  still showed the same error as blocked port.So I tried with different ports ,again I am getting same error for all the ports whichever I give. Can anybody help me to sort out this issue and Why it is giving same error for all ports?

Comment: Please add the error message and more details reg which config files you are editing

Comment: [Apache]       Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: I am editing port numbers in Apache(httpd.conf) for port 80 and Apache(httpd-ssl.conf) for 443

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly I think you are referring to similar issue

Comment: Thank you for the reply