# Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

i have an issue with Apache server 
this problem happened suddenly
when i'm trying to start Apache server i got the following error:

```
2:16:01 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
2:16:01 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
2:16:01 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
2:16:01 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
2:16:01 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
2:16:01 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
2:16:01 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Apache Error Log

```
[Thu May 07 02:16:01.255412 2020] [core:warn] [pid 10552:tid 584] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Thu May 07 02:16:01.260361 2020] [:emerg] [pid 10552:tid 584] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

i tried to change ports an reinstall XAMPP but nothing works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you share some details of your Apache environment? Please review the SO [guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and have a quick read of [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) which contains a checklist of actions to take before asking a question.

Comment: @Joundill i already added all information

Comment: > that's will may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly