# How to Create Valid SSL in localhost for XAMPP

Tags: php, windows, apache, ssl, xampp

How can I use a secure connection (**SSL**) in my **`XAMPP`** in windows?

I get the following error when I open the localhost page:

> connection not secure

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In my XAMPP install I basically  have a clone to all the site that I managed.  And All of them (of course) use SSL/HTTPS.

[image]

**Here’s the step by  step guide:**

In this step we are going to crate `SSL` and setup “site.test” website.

[image]

**1. Navigate to Apache directory in XAMPP.**

In regular install it’s in C:\xampp\apache.

[image]

**2. Create a folder in that page.**

This is where we will store our cert. In this example I will create “crt” folder. So we will have `C:\xampp\apache\crt`

[image]

**3. Add this files.**

- [cert.conf](https://gist.github.com/turtlepod/3b8d8d0eef29de019951aa9d9dcba546)
- [make-cert.bat](https://gist.github.com/turtlepod/e94928cddbfc46cfbaf8c3e5856577d0)

[image]

**4. Edit cert.conf and Run make-cert.bat**

Change **{{DOMAIN}}** text using the domain we want to use, in this case **site.test** and save.

Double click the make-cert.bat and input the domain site.test when prompted. And just do enter in other question since we already set the default from cert.conf.

[image]

> **Note**: I don’t know how to do text replace in .bat script, if you do, let me know in the comment how to do it and I will update make-cert.bat to automatically replace the {{DOMAIN}} with the domain input.

[image]

**5. Install the cert in windows.**

After that, you will see site.test folder created. In that folder we will have **server.crt** and **server.key**. This is our SSL certificate.

Double click on the **server.crt** to install it on Windows so Windows can trust it.

[image]

And then select **Local Machine** as Store Location.

[image]

And then Select “**Place all certificate in the following store**” and click **browse** and select **Trusted Root Certification Authorities**.

[image]

Click **Next** and **Finish**.

And now this cert is installed and trusted in Windows. The next thing is how to use this cert in XAMPP.

[image]

**6. Add the site in Windows hosts**

- Open Notepad as administrator.
- Edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (the file have no ext)
- Add this in a new line:

```
127.0.0.1 site.test
```

This will tell windows to load **XAMPP** when we visit `http://site.test` You can try and it will show XAMPP dashboard page.

[image]

**7. Add the site in XAMPP conf.**

We need to enable SSL for this domain and let **XAMPP** know where we store the **SSL** Cert. So we need to edit `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`

And add this code at the bottom:

```
 ## site.test
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName site.test
     ServerAlias *.site.test
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName site.test
     ServerAlias *.site.test
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile "crt/site.test/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/site.test/server.key"
 </VirtualHost>
```

After that, you will need to restart Apache in XAMPP.  It’s very simple, simply open XAMPP Control Panel and **Stop** and re-**Start** Apache Module.

> **Tips**: In XAMPP conf, as you can see you can change the domain root directory if needed. Eg. as sub-dir in htdocs.

[image]

**8. Restart your browser and Done!**

This is required to load the certificate. And visit the domain on your browser, and you will see green lock!

[image]

[image]

I hope this tutorial is useful!

Source: https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-valid-ssl-in-localhost-for-xampp/

Comment: helloi do all setup but not work

Comment: Excellent, especially the part to register the certs correctly with Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities

Comment: for me i just had to replace the certificate and key with a new one in
"conf/ssl.crt/server.crt",
"conf/ssl.key/server.key"

Comment: while entering  site.test/wordpress it redirects to localhost/wordpress. not getting the url like site.test/wordpress

Comment: Thanks, It's working now. but it's ok while using http protocol, but not in https. browser sys its not secure while using https://. can you little elaborate that?

Comment: to replace the text in .bat file. you have open note pad ( run as administrator)  and open the .bat file from note pad file menu.

Comment: First had an error with the bin path which does not exists. Then had another problem, got an error when starting Apache. Instead of putting the virtual host in httpd-xampp.conf I put only the ssl part (virtual host on port 443)  in C:\xampp8\apache\conf\extra\https-ssl.conf. Restarted Apache, it worked :)

Comment: I added these to php.ini for those for whom this doesn't work: `openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt"` and `openssl.capath="C:\xampp\apache\conf\"`. Not sure if that was necessary, but it solved my issue after restarting XAMPP's apache instance!

Comment: How the hell did this work for me ?? thank you so so so much , god bless you