# Apache on XAMPP not running on windows 11

Tags: apache, xampp

on windows 10 apache was running without any issues after I updated my windows from windows 10 to 11,
I tried everything on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly) and it didn't work at all and I tried to install deferent versions of XAMPP and it didn't work at all

and the only thing that I notice that windows defender didn't give me an alert for access,
idk if that is the problem, and I tried to give it access manually and it didn't work as well
note: MySQL running perfectly.

Comment: I run Xampp on win11 without any issues

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Same issue I'm facing. In windows logs event I noticed php get crashed due to which apache not start.

Comment: @MikeMoy could you please confirm xampp version you are using for win11

Comment: v3.3.0 (I installed windows 11 from scratch, and I installed xammp from scratch)