# How to solve the error of xampp as Apache?

Tags: xampp

> 8:29:18 PM  [Apache]  Status change detected: running 8:29:28 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped 8:29:28 PM  [Apache]
> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. 8:29:28 PM  [Apache]
> This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  8:29:28 PM
> [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, o

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBhAt.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/how-to-solve-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly)